# Rust and PostgreSQL with tokio_postgres

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, tokio-postgres

I have a PostgreSQL database with one simple table:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE test_database;
\c test_database;
CREATE TABLE users ( id int primary key NOT NULL, name varchar(40) NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO users (id,name) VALUES (1, 'user_one');
INSERT INTO users (id,name) VALUES (2, 'user_two');
```

Now I want to write a rust program that retrieves users with `SELECT id, name FROM users` and returns them.
For this I picked `tokio_postgres`, as it is asynchronous and it seems to have support with Tokio async runtime.

This is my program:

```rust
mod domain;
mod types;
use tokio_postgres::NoTls;
use types::AsyncResult;

// Using Tokio runtime for async behaviour: https://crates.io/crates/tokio
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> AsyncResult<()> {
  // Get DB client and connection
  let (client, connection) = tokio_postgres::connect(
    "postgres://test_user:secret_password@localhost/test_database",
    NoTls,
  )
  .await?;

  // Spawn connection
  tokio::spawn(async move {
    if let Err(error) = connection.await {
      eprintln!("Connection error: {}", error);
    }
  });

  // Do the query
  let users = client.query("SELECT id, name FROM users", &[]).await?;

  println!("{:#?}", users);

  Ok(())
}
```

From this I expect to get something similar to:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "user_1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "user_2"
  }
]
```

But instead I receive the table structure:

```
[
  Row {
    columns: [
      Column {
        name: "id",
        type: Int4,
      },
      Column {
        name: "name",
        type: Varchar,
      },
    ],
  },
  Row {
    columns: [
      Column {
        name: "id",
        type: Int4,
      },
      Column {
        name: "name",
        type: Varchar,
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

I tried everything, but I cant't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: did you  try to read the documentation of the library you used? https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.7.5/tokio_postgres/row/struct.Row.html
https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.7.5/tokio_postgres/struct.Column.html

Comment: Yes, I did try to read the documentation of the library I used.

Comment: You need a mapper [(see tokio_pg_mapper)](https://docs.rs/tokio-pg-mapper/0.2.0/tokio_pg_mapper/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any reason why the sql client doesnt include it?

Comment: You can do it without a mapper using [`FromSql trait`](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.7.5/tokio_postgres/types/trait.FromSql.html#tymethod.from_sql). If you take a look into `tokio_pg_mapper` it is certainly what they do.

Comment: @Jerboas86 got it, I'm on it with `FromSql` trait. Once the trait is set, how do you trigger the from_sql function? Any good example out there? I'm trying to find something clear, but I can't find any implemented minimal example.

Answer (score 4):

Found a way to map PosgreSQL to my User model. I used `impl From<Row>`, and then:

```rust
let result = client.query("SELECT id, name FROM users", &[]).await?;

let users: Vec<User> = result.into_iter().map(|row| User::from(row)).collect();
```

Using `iter()` wont work, I suppose because it returns `&T` instead of `T`, but I'm not sure yet. `into_iter()`, which consumes the vector, returns `T`, works. This is not documented anywhere, or at least it was impossible to find a proper example, which I think is one of the main drawbacks of Rust.

Here a playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=39cb31181880457313c2d0e47a692b7a

And here the code for reference:

```rust
mod domain;
mod types;
use tokio_postgres::{NoTls, Row};
use types::AsyncResult;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct User {
  pub id: i32,
  pub name: String,
}

impl From<Row> for User {
  fn from(row: Row) -> Self {
    Self {
      id: row.get("id"),
      name: row.get("name"),
    }
  }
}

// Using Tokio runtime for async behaviour: https://crates.io/crates/tokio
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> AsyncResult<()> {
  // Get DB client and connection
  let (client, connection) = tokio_postgres::connect(
    "postgres://test_user:secret_password@localhost/test_database",
    NoTls,
  )
  .await?;

  // Spawn connection
  tokio::spawn(async move {
    if let Err(error) = connection.await {
      eprintln!("Connection error: {}", error);
    }
  });

  // Do the query
  let result = client.query("SELECT id, name FROM users", &[]).await?;

  let users: Vec<User> = result.into_iter().map(|row| User::from(row)).collect();

  println!("{:#?}", users);
  Ok(())
}
```

I'm not sure that this is the proper way to do it, if its good practice or if there are better ways to do it. Any advice will be welcome.